# Dispaying All Data Points between two ranges

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that has several rows out lining ranges between two zip codes for each state. I am hoping to be able to take the two ranges and display every value between the two ranges on their own separate line. EX below.

```
Zip Start   Zip End     State
00501       06390       NY
10001       10314       NY
10451       11003       NY
```

I am hoping to display the data as

```
00501    NY
00502    NY
00503    NY
00504    NY
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS yourTable;
CREATE TABLE yourTable as
Select '00501' as zipstart,'06390' as zipend,'NY' as state union
select'10001','10314','NY'union
select'10451','11003','NY'

Distributed by (ZipStart,ZipEnd,State);

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM
       (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n)
)

, cteTally AS (
    SELECT
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as Num
    FROM
       cte c1
       CROSS JOIN cte c2
       CROSS JOIN cte c3
       CROSS JOIN cte c4
       CROSS JOIN cte c5
)

SELECT
    SUBSTRING(ZipStart || CAST(tt.Num AS VARCHAR(100)),1,5) ZipSTart
    ,t.zipend,t.State
FROM
    yourTable t
    INNER JOIN cteTally tt
    ON tt.Num <= CAST(t.ZipEnd AS INT)
    AND tt.Num >= CAST(t.ZipStart AS INT)
```

Comment: What have you already tried and what problem(s) did you experience?

Comment: Originally this was done in SQL server using hard coded values and a temp table. We are now in PGAdmin and the application can no longer handle the large list of values.

I am hoping to use this in a subquery for a larger report. Thank you

Comment: Okay... so is this is using SQL Server or PostgresSql? Pick one.

Comment: @SqlZim voted to close for that reason.

Comment: Show us the code that "the application can no longer handle"

Comment: The `cteTally` can be replaced with a simple `generate_series(1, 100000)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL

```
select  to_char(zip,'FM00000') as zip
       ,state

from    t,generate_series("Zip Start"::int,"Zip End"::int) gs(zip)
;
```

Comment: +1 I agree on PostgreSQL specifically (and the platforms that support) generate_series is a much easier way for this case AND if a tally table does need to be actually generated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Sql server version that does work on PostgreSQL and several other platforms. that handles up to 100,000 numbers to expand simply add more cross join's in the cteTally definition.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#yourTable') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #yourTable
    END

CREATE TABLE #yourTable (ZipStart VARCHAR(5), ZipEnd VARCHAR(5), State CHAR(2));
INSERT INTO #yourTable VALUES
('00501','06390','NY')
,('10001','10314','NY')
,('10451','11003','NY');

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM
       (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n)
)

, cteTally AS (
    SELECT
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as Num
    FROM
       cte c1 --10
       CROSS JOIN cte c2 --100
       CROSS JOIN cte c3 --1,000
       CROSS JOIN cte c4 --10,000
       CROSS JOIN cte c5 --100,000
)

SELECT
    RIGHT('00000' || CAST(tt.Num AS VARCHAR(100)),5) as GeneratedZip
    ,t.ZipStart
    ,t.ZipEnd
    ,t.State
FROM
    #yourTable t
    INNER JOIN cteTally tt
    ON tt.Num <= CAST(t.ZipEnd AS INT)
    AND tt.Num >= CAST(t.ZipStart AS INT)
```

and for PostgreSQL specifically and the platforms that support `generate_series` check out [Dudu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41066552/5510627)

Comment: No problem.  We're all entitled the occasional "Mr. Magoo moment"   My wife keeps a list of mine

Comment: Hello Matt, Thank you for your help. Just to clarify I need the Postgres Version. However I must have an older version of PGAdmin because I've had to make some modification to get it to work run. My report runs but only shows the initial 3 temp table values several thousand times.

Comment: @Matt Apologies I am not familiar with how to post the code in the comments. I have amended the original question with the new code towards the bottom.

Comment: @Garrett updating the question is what I meant.  you are getting the temp table values several thousand times because of `SUBSTRING(ZipStart || CAST(tt.Num AS VARCHAR(100)),1,5) ZipSTart` you need to use the `RIGHT('0000' + ...` that is in my code your `substring` just gives you the `ZipStart` every time it is run.  I added columns and alias to the postgressql version in my code hopefully it will make it more clear.  `tt.Num` will be the expanded/generated zip code the `'00000'` is just to format it with leading 0's

Comment: @Garrett: see Dudu Markovitz's answer - that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> This is for **Sql Server**. I'll leave it here just because I took the time to write it.

This is pretty simple with a numbers table.

rextester: http://rextester.com/MEFE32862

numbers table stolen from [@AaronBertrand's article on generating a set](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1).

```
begin;
create table dbo.zip_ranges (id int ,StateName varchar(32) ,[State] char(2) ,Zip_Start int ,Zip_End int ) 
  insert into dbo.zip_ranges (id, StateName, [State], Zip_Start, Zip_End) values  
    (1 ,'New York (Fishers Is)' ,'NY' ,501 ,6390) ,(2 ,'New York' ,'NY' ,10001 ,10314),(3 ,'New York' ,'NY' ,10001 ,10314) ,(4 ,'Ohio' ,'OH' ,43001 ,45999) 
  create unique clustered index n on dbo.zip_ranges(Id)
end;
/* 100,000 number table - stolen from @AaronBertrand https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1 */  
begin;
  select top (100000) n = convert(int, row_number() over (order by s1.[object_id]))
    into dbo.numbers
    from sys.all_objects as s1 
      cross join sys.all_objects as s2
    option (maxdop 1);
  create unique clustered index n on dbo.numbers(n)
end;

select 
        --Zip=n.n
        --Zip=left('00000',5-len(n.n))+convert(varchar(5),n.n)
        Zip=right('00000'+convert(varchar(5),n.n),5) /* grabbed this conversion from @Matt instead of my clunky one */
      , z.[State]

from dbo.zip_ranges z
    inner join dbo.numbers n on n >= z.zip_start and n <= z.zip_end
    where z.[State]='NY'
    order by n
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this question was originally tagged for sql-server.